# php mvc url pattern which takes three arguments

Tags: php, url, model-view-controller

I'm new to MVC. what I've learned from a few articles and some videos is that the general form of URL in MVC structure is as ***controller/action***. but I've come across some URLs like this:

[www.exmaple.com/users/login/confirm](http://www.exmaple.com/users/login/confirm)

which takes three parameters(users, login, confirm). I don't understand which one is the controller, which one is the action, and what the third parameter is.

On the same website, there is also such URL:

[www.exmaple.com/users/login-register](http://www.exmaple.com/users/login-register)

so, how does it know when to treat the second parameter as the action and when as the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a **one rule for all** to map your URLs as `controller/action`. It is just a common practice most people use.

For example the one you mentioned in question, `users/login/confirm`, is literally used for confirming an event related to the `login`. Why it is not `users/confirm`? Well the reason might be that the route `users\confirm` is used for another operation like registration confirmation or confirming user addition by admin or etc. So in the application there was multiple **confirmation** logic so the programmer just segregated them with another parameter (login here).

The best way to understand what is going on behind the scenes is just to read the code or documentation of that code.

**Note**: It is important to understand the value of clean URL here, since if it was clean from the start, you wouldn't have had these issues with understanding the logic.